# How to transform diacritics/accents to latex macro using a command line tool?

Tags: accents, input-encodings

My latex document has latin1/utf-8 diacritics/accents such as `é`

I want to run `a-transform-program file.tex > file-ascii.tex` so that all diacritics/accents are replaced by their corresponding macros.

Is there such a `a-transform-program`?

Comment: What's wrong with search and replace?

Comment: Consider the possibility of compiling with LuaLaTeX and fontspec, instead of what you are using now. UTF-8 characters can be used directly.

Answer (score 1):

Using module [latex](ftp://ftp.fau.de/ctan/biblio/bibtex/utils/mab2bib/latex.py) from [mab2bib](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/utils/mab2bib?lang=en), it's a python one-liner:

```
 python -c 'import latex,codecs; latex.register(); print unicode(codecs.open("myfile.tex",encoding="utf-8").read()).encode("latex")'
```